# Redirecting to respective page of desktop/mobile version using Javascript

Tags: javascript, redirect

I have different domain names for mobile (http://m.mydomain.com) and desktop (http://web.mydomain.com) users. I am currently using following Javascript code to redirect my desktop users accessing mobile URLs to desktop URLs.

```js
<script>
var isDesktop = {
    Windows: function() {
        return navigator.platform.match('Win32|Win16|Win64|WinCE|Windows');
    },
    Mac: function() {
        return navigator.platform.match('MacIntel|Macintosh|MacPPC|Mac68K');
    },
    any: function() {
        return (isDesktop.Windows() || isDesktop.Mac());
    }
};
  
 if (isDesktop.any()){
  window.location='http://web.mydomain.com';
 }
</script>
```

But the issue is: The user is redirected to main-page (http://web.mydomain.com) no matter on which page he is. I want to redirect them to the respective page. For example, if a desktop user is accessing the mobile page http://m.mydomain.com/a-page, he is automatically redirected to desktop version of that page http://web.mydomain.com/a-page.

I can't use .htaccess because my web-server is Nginx.

Comment: Refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser). Get yourself similar function and check if user visits your site using a mobile brower. If so, then redirect to the mobile site.

Comment: I'm already able to detect the mobile user and redirect them. I am asking how do I redirect them to the same page on desktop URL.

Answer (score 0):

If you're supporting modern browsers only, the [URL API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) allows you to extract the path name from the URL. Refer to the below example, which converts the mobile URL to the web URL.

```js
// Base URLs for mobile and web based sites.
var mobileBaseUrl = "http://m.mydomain.com";
var webBaseUrl = "http://web.mydomain.com";

// The actual page URL
var loc = "http://m.mydomain.com/what/ever/the/url";
var url = new URL(loc);

// Converted location
var result = `${webBaseUrl}${url.pathname}`;
console.log(result);
```